# Problem with react-router-dom while importing plain router from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I need to create custom history for that I created this file

```js
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

export default createHistory();
```

and importing this in my App.js file which looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import StreamList from "./streams/streamList";
import StreamCreate from "./streams/streamCreate";
import StreamDelete from "./streams/streamDelete";
import StreamEdit from "./streams/streamEdit";
import StreamShow from "./streams/streamShow";
import Header from "./header";
import history from "../history";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Router hitory={history}>
        <Header />
        <Route path="/" exact component={StreamList} />
        <Route path="/streams/new" component={StreamCreate} />
        <Route path="/streams/edit" component={StreamEdit} />
        <Route path="/streams/delete" component={StreamDelete} />
        <Route path="/streams/show" component={StreamShow} />
      </Router>
```

and getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined new Router E:/xord/streams/modules/Router.js:20   17 | super(props);   18 |    19 | this.state = { > 20 |   location: props.history.location

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is the missing `<Switch />` component between `<Router />` and the `<Route />` components. See from the documentation of [`<Switch />`](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch):

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

Try adding as the following:

```
<Router hitory={history}>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={StreamList} />
        <Route path="/streams/new" component={StreamCreate} />
        <Route path="/streams/edit" component={StreamEdit} />
        <Route path="/streams/delete" component={StreamDelete} />
        <Route path="/streams/show" component={StreamShow} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thanks. will try that and get back to you if find any issues.

Comment: Hi, I did the same as you told but still getting the same error.

Comment: Anyone else would like to hellp?